# "Invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string" error for Microsoft Edge and how to add "w3c: false" capability?

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

I'm getting an **"invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string"** error for **Microsoft Edge**.

I think the problem will be fixed when I add **"w3c:false"** capability.

***Code block for "w3c: false":***

```
if (CustomRunner.deviceThreadLocal.get().getBrowser().equals(BrowserType.EDGE)) {

  EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
  edgeOptions.setCapability("w3c", false);
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(EdgeOptions.CAPABILITY, edgeOptions);
  edgeOptions.merge(capabilities);

}
```

***EdgeOptions.java:***

```
package org.openqa.selenium.edge;

import static org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY;

import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import java.util.Objects;

public class EdgeOptions extends MutableCapabilities {

  public EdgeOptions() {
    setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.EDGE);
  }

  @Override
  public EdgeOptions merge(Capabilities extraCapabilities) {
    super.merge(extraCapabilities);
    return this;
  }


  public void setPageLoadStrategy(String strategy) {
    setCapability(PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, Objects.requireNonNull(strategy));
  }

  public EdgeOptions setProxy(Proxy proxy) {
    setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    return this;
  }
}
```

But when I want to add this capability, I cannot run the code because there is no **CAPABILITY** in **EdgeOptions.java**.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about how you use the `handle`, but for the issue about adding `w3c:false`, that's due to selenium server version. The issue will occur when you use selenium server 3.141.59. I use **selenium sever 4.0.0 beta 2** and it works well with the code below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


public class Edgedisablew3c {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "Your_path_here\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
         EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
         DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    
         capabilities.setCapability(EdgeOptions.CAPABILITY, edgeOptions);
         capabilities.setCapability("w3c", false);
         edgeOptions.merge(capabilities);       
            
         WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
         driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            
         System.out.println(capabilities.getCapability("w3c")); //Getting the value of w3c to verify it.
         
         driver.close();
         driver.quit();
    }
}
```